# Ajax success function not working with returned json data and status 200/304

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, ajax

I'm making an AJAX call that returns a JSON object, and is successfully the JSON in browser. However, the success function isn't fired but rather the error block is hit with the message only saying "error" which isn't much to go on. The status is either 200 or 304 and I can see the object on the network in developer tools so it's there but I can't access that object in the success function.

Here is the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    dataType: "json",
    jsonp: "false",
    url: "http://my.api.url:8080/quote",                                                                                          
    success: function(r){
        var q = r;
        $("#quote").append(q);
},
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(xhr);
    }
});
```

The JSON:

```
{"msg":[{"quote":"quote goes here"}]}
```

The JSON is generated by an express/node application with response.json() if that effect things, I'm relatively new to those. I have tried setting the jsonp to false, using contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', over datatype json, among other ineffective tries. Any help/critiques are appreciated.

Comment: can you try with `complete`, too? same function as success. success will only trigger if you have a http-header 200.

Comment: @zer02 No, I haven't tried that. I'll give it a shot thanks.

Comment: @zer02 that didn't get it unfortunately.

Comment: Have you tried: `response.json({success : "works!", status : 200});`

Comment: Yes, the JSON is being passed from the server to the browser. It's the ajax call that is failing here. I can view the JSON response on the url and in developer tools.

Comment: Try this? : `$.get( "http://my.api.url:8080/quote", function( data ) {
        $("#quote").append(data);
});`

Comment: @zer02 Already tried $.get() and $.getJSON(), but neither have worked.

Comment: @zer02 Thanks for the helpful suggestions; they are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem here is actually CORS,cross origin resource sharing, since jQuery is calling the API from  a different port CORS was blocking the resulting JSON data as per the safety standard. A simple middleware addition to the node.js app adjusting the headers for dealing with CORS solves the problem e.g.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With,Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
```

So the json was essentially in the browser but inaccessible to any scripts because of the headers. These pages helped a lot should someone else encounter this problem.

[Enable Cors](https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html)
[Mozilla Dev](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Cross-origin_network_access)